# set dictionary key function in python

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

I was wondering how to create a function to set the key of a dictionary. Consider the following class:

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
```

Now lets instantiate the object:

```py
a_dog = Dog("Berty", "Hollows")
```

Now I want to create a function, which returns either the first name or the last name, depending on which parameter I pass into it. My idea was something like:

```py
def return_dogs_name(dog, get_dict_key(x)):
     return dog.get_dict_key(x)
```

with

```py
def get_dict_key(x):
    return x
```

however, that does not work.

My desired output would look like

```py
return_dogs_name(a_dog, get_dict_key("first_name"))
>>> Berty
```

How would such a function look like?

Answer (score 7):

You can make use of [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

def return_dogs_name(dog, attrName):
     return getattr(dog, attrName)

a_dog = Dog("Berty", "Hollows")
print(return_dogs_name(a_dog, 'first_name'))
```

Out:

```
Berty
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary within your function

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

a_dog = Dog("Berty", "Hollows")

def return_dogs_name(dog,which_name):
    return {'first': dog.first_name,'last': dog.last_name}.get(which_name,'unknown')

print(return_dogs_name(a_dog,'last'))
```

Output :

```
Hollows
```